# DbContext set<> include dont work

Tags: entity-framework, include, dbcontext

```
//Site entity
public class Site
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Language> Languages { get; set; }
}
//language entity
public class Language
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Site> Sites { get; set; }
}
//my context with custom connection and transaction
public class PortalBaseContext : DbContext
{
    public PortalBaseContext(DbConnection conn)
        : base(conn, false)
    {
        Database.UseTransaction((DbTransaction)PersistContext.Transaction);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Site>().ToTable("TblSite");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Language>().ToTable("TblLanguage");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Site>().
                                     HasMany(c => c.Languages).
                                     WithMany(p => p.Sites).
                                     Map(
                                      m =>
                                      {
                                          m.MapLeftKey("LanguageId");
                                          m.MapRightKey("SiteId");
                                          m.ToTable("TblSiteLanguage");
                                      });
    }

    public DbSet<Site> TblSite { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Language> TblLanguage { get; set; }
}


PortalBaseContext c = new PortalBaseContext( );
//Part1
DbSet<Site> query = c.Set<Site>();
query.Include("Languages");
lst = query.ToList();

//Part2
//lst = c.TblSite.Include("Languages").ToList();
```

in part1 include not work!!
if comment part1 and use part2 include work correctly!!

i use custom connection and transaction per request and want load 
sub property for each class.

in part1 include not work!!
if comment part1 and use part2 include work correctly!!

i use custom connection and transaction per request and want load 
sub property for each class.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not work"? Is there a specific exception or unexpected behavior you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Include` is a non destructive method. It returns a new enumerable where each item will have the specified related entities loaded when materialized; the original `DBSet` you're invoking it on isn't modified in any way.

You need to apply `ToList` to the value returned by `Include`. Change this:

```
DbSet<Site> query = c.Set<Site>();
query.Include("Languages");
lst = query.ToList();
```

to this:

```
DbSet<Site> query = c.Set<Site>();
lst = query.Include("Languages").ToList();
```